# Problems with hardware clock on my ThinkPad T420 after flashing Coreboot

Tags: linux, arch-linux, hardware, thinkpad, coreboot

After flashing coreboot I get the wrong date on my linux install.

```
# date
Mon 21 Mar 2089 04:03:42 AM UTC
```

And when I try to read the date with hwclock I get this error

```
# hwclock -r
hwclock: ioctl(RTC_RD_TIME) to /dev/rtc0 to read the time failed: Invalid argument
```

[Here's the output of dmesg](https://pastebin.com/itnDaa0i)

Could this be caused by a dying/dead CMOS battery ?

Thanks in advance!

PD: If I boot coreinfo I see what it seems to be an invalid date on the bottom right (71/131/1983 - 52:16:58).

Comment: Can you try with the [--directisa](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problems_with_hwclock) switch to bypass the rtc driver? `hwclock --directisa -r`

Comment: It's able to read but I get a wrong date (2069-02-05 19:53:40.398181+00:00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys at the coreboot's IRC channel pointed out that the problem probably was that the nvram got corrupted.

Setting the correct time and then writing it with the hwclock command (bypassing the rtc driver as suggested by Stefan in the comments) did the trick.

```
hwclock --directisa -w
```

Many thanks :)